# VBA = How to extract specific rows in new workbook?

Tags: vba

I'm trying to open the datafile ("srcWB", sample data below in table), extract certain values into a new workbook (macro=CreateNewWorkBook). Only trying to extract the names in the "online_status" of the ones that meet this criteria;

- Email_sent = "Complete" And Email_Id <> "" (Doesnt have any text)
- Email_sent = "Not Started" And Email_Id = "" (Has any text/isn't empty)

***Issue: Can't get the intended output in the new workbook***

**srcWB**

| Online_Status | Email_sent | Email_Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ExtractedData | Complete |  |
| ExtractedData | Complete |  |
| ExtractedData | Complete |  |
| ExtractedData | Complete |  |
| InputData | Not Started | Completed |
| InputData | Not Started | Completed |
| OutData | Not Sent | Completed |
| OutData | Not Sent | Completed |
| OutData | Not Sent | Completed |

```
Sub Status_Validation()

Online_Status = "A"
Email_sent = "B"
Email_Id = "C"

Reason_Column = "B"

'Call Open_srcWB
'Set srcWB = ActiveWorkbook

Call CreateNewWorkBook

rownum = 2

While Cells(rownum, Online_Status).Value <> ""
     
    startrow = rownum
     
    taskname = srcWB.Cells(rownum, Online_Status).Value
     
    While Cells(rownum + 1, Online_Status).Value = taskname
      rownum = rownum + 1
    Wend
     
    endrow = rownum

    For j = startrow To endrow
      completion1 = Cells(j, Email_sent).Value
      completion2 = Cells(j, Email_Id).Value
       
      'These lines are only applying to the startrow
      If j = startrow Then
        If (completion1 = "Complete" And completion2 = "") Then
          taskstatus = 1
          GoTo there:
          'move on to check next row
        ElseIf (completion1 = "Not Started" AND completion2 <> "") Then
           taskstatus = 2
          GoTo there:
          'move on to check next row
        End If
      End If
      
there:
    Next j

here:

If taskstatus = 1 Then
      Status_update = "Not Sent"
    ElseIf taskstatus = 2 Then
      Status_update = "Sending in Progress"
    End If

StatusCheck.Range(Cells(startrow, Reason_Column), Cells(endrow, Reason_Column)).Value = Status_update
   
    rownum = rownum + 1
     
  Wend
End Sub
```

```
Sub CreateNewWorkBook()

Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
"\\src.wb.xlsx"

Set StatusCheck = ActiveWorkbook

StatusCheck.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Online_Status"
StatusCheck.Sheets(1).Range("B1").Value = "Reason"

End Sub
```

**Output**

| Online_Status | Reason |
| --- | --- |
| ExtractedData | Not Sent |
| InputData | Sending in Progress |

Comment: Is the output the expected output or the "wrong" output you are getting?  Also `ElseIf (completion1 = "Not Started" AND completion1 = "")` can never be true, since you are comparing one cell with two contradicting criterias.

Comment: Note that `= ""` equals "*no* text" and `<> ""`  equals "*not* empty"

Comment: `ElseIf taskstatus = 2` will also probably never be valid, since nothing will set taskstatus to 2.

Comment: The errors you all pointed out have been updated into the code but still nothing

Comment: Nothing? You should get an object error. Your first problem is that variables doesn't carry over between subs. So `Status_Validation` has no idea what `StatusCheck` is supposed to be. Easiest fix would be to not run that as a separate sub, or make it a function that returns the  `StatusCheck`

Comment: Your second problem is that you are opening and activating a new workbook, but you are referring to the "Activesheet" in a lot of places when you mean to address the source book. `While Cells(` is equal to `While ActiveSheet.Cells(` see new code in answer.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but there seems to be some reduntand `loops` and `goto`.
The while loop should work exactly the same if you instead of this:

```
While Cells(rownum, Online_Status).Value <> ""    
    startrow = rownum
    taskname = srcWB.Cells(rownum, Online_Status).Value
    While Cells(rownum + 1, Online_Status).Value = taskname
      rownum = rownum + 1
    Wend     
    endrow = rownum
    For j = startrow To endrow
      completion1 = Cells(j, Email_sent).Value
      completion2 = Cells(j, Email_Id).Value
      'These lines are only applying to the startrow
      If j = startrow Then 
'--This invalidates the previous loop, since it will only execute on the first run.
'--Remove both loops and replace j
        If (completion1 = "Complete" And completion2 <> "") Then
          taskstatus = 1 '-- Why not just set Status_update here?
          GoTo there:
'-- This just exits the if, which is what happens anyway, redundant
          'move on to check next row
        ElseIf (completion1 = "Not Started" AND completion1 = "") Then
          GoTo there: '-- Also redundant
          'move on to check next row
        End If
      End If
      
there: '-- Can't see why we'd need the labels
    Next j

here:

If taskstatus = 1 Then
      Status_update = "Not Sent"
    ElseIf taskstatus = 2 Then
      Status_update = "Sending in Progress"
    End If
'-- The entire If can be removed if we just set Status_update directly

StatusCheck.Range(Cells(startrow, Reason_Column), Cells(endrow, Reason_Column)).Value = Status_update
    rownum = rownum + 1 
  Wend
```

Just short it down to:

```
While Cells(rownum, Online_Status).Value <> ""
    startrow = rownum
    taskname = srcWB.Cells(rownum, Online_Status).Value
    While Cells(rownum + 1, Online_Status).Value = taskname
      rownum = rownum + 1
    Wend
    completion1 = Cells(startrow, Email_sent).Value
    completion2 = Cells(startrow, Email_Id).Value
    If (completion1 = "Complete" And completion2 = "") Then
        Status_update = "Not Sent"
    ElseIf (completion1 = "Not Started" And completion2 <> "") Then
        Status_update = "Sending in Progress"
    End If
StatusCheck.Range(Cells(startrow, Reason_Column), Cells(endrow, Reason_Column)).Value = Status_update
    rownum = rownum + 1
Wend
```

I did make some changes based on assumption, like:

- That the `completion2 <> ""`should be reversed, looking at your
  example data.
- the thrid `completion1` is actually supposed to be `completion2`
- That `completion1 = "Not Started"` would set `tasktatus = 2`

I can't debug beyond this, since I have no idea what `CreateNewWorkBook_StatusValidation` does, and what `StatusCheck` is.

Changing the second sub to a function, returning the variable, or just running the workbook creation code in the sub directly should fic your problems:

```
Sub Status_Validation()

Online_Status = "A"
Email_sent = "B"
Email_Id = "C"
Reason_Column = "B"

'Call Open_srcWB
Set srcWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set srcSH = srcWB.Worksheets(1)

Set StatusCheck = CreateNewWorkBook

rownum = 2

While srcSH.Cells(rownum, Online_Status).Value <> ""
    startrow = rownum
    taskname = srcSH.Cells(rownum, Online_Status).Value
    While srcSH.Cells(rownum + 1, Online_Status).Value = taskname
      rownum = rownum + 1
    Wend
    endrow = rownum
    completion1 = srcSH.Cells(startrow, Email_sent).Value
    completion2 = srcSH.Cells(startrow, Email_Id).Value
    If (completion1 = "Complete" And completion2 = "") Then
        Status_update = "Not Sent"
    ElseIf (completion1 = "Not Started" And completion2 <> "") Then
        Status_update = "Sending in Progress"
    End If
    StatusCheck.Range(Cells(startrow, Reason_Column), Cells(endrow, Reason_Column)).Value = Status_update
    rownum = rownum + 1
Wend
End Sub


Private Function CreateNewWorkBook() As Object

Workbooks.Add
'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
'"\\src.wb.xlsx"

Set StatusCheck = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

StatusCheck.Range("A1").Value = "Online_Status"
StatusCheck.Range("B1").Value = "Reason"
Set CreateNewWorkBook = StatusCheck
End Function
```

But I'm not sure the output is exactly what you want. You aren't passing "Online_Status" column for example. And why you would want to fill from `startrow` to `endrow` with the same value eludes me.

Comment: StatusCheck is the variable name assigned to the new workbook I created.  It has been updated in the code. Getting the desired output is the issue. @Christofer Weber